# Is there a way to fix missing icon for Visual Studio Code on Wayland?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, electron, wayland

I have a problem with vscode if I run it on Wayland natively. Instead of appropriate icon I got a generic icon for Wayland applications as on screenshot.

I have tried to find a temporary solution editing .desktop files of vscode, but without success. As I know, the problem is in the wrong wmclass which  sets on startup of vscode.

Upd:

I've got update from the AUR, which fixes all my issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling with this problem too.
I have tried to find solution and find a few issues
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129953
Please check last messages at that discussion.

You can try to substitute value of WMClass with visual-studio-code of Code

```
StartupWMClass=code-url-handler
```

Also there is solution like this
"The problem can also be resolved by modifying the desktopName entry in /opt/visual-studio-code/resources/app/package.json to "desktopName": "visual-studio-code.desktop"" from that discussion too.